# How To Fix This Strange Font Rendering on Android?

Tags: android, google-chrome, fonts

The following screenshot is taken from a Nexus 6 browsing on Chrome 49 on Android 6.0.1. The "s" and "t" --- when they appear together --- are joined by a line. This is not intended. It renders fine everywhere else. QUESTION: Have you seen this or something similar before? Can you suggest avenues of research to solve?

http://www.screencast.com/t/xSZu8iyWbhbo

Comment: I get an Access Denied xml error message trying to view your screenshot.

Comment: Uh Oh. Thank you for letting me know. I will try another method of uploading to a server. Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation on Stack Overflow to embed an image in the post

Comment: new link in post. thank you

Comment: @BarakKassar did you ever solve this? having the same issue